# Making Microsoft Unity dependency properties available in constructors

Tags: c#, unity-container

I've got the following bit of (simplified) code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  [Dependency]
  public IRequiredService RequiredService { get; set; }

  protected string RequiredParameter { get; private set; }

  public BaseClass(string requiredParameter)
  {
    this.RequiredParameter = requiredParameter;
  }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public DerivedClass(string requiredParameter) : base(requiredParameter)
  {
    RequiredService.DoSomething(); //this will fail!
  }
}
```

In other words, I'd like to have access to the Unity-filled `RequiredService` in the constructor... but that's impossible, since that property hasn't been filled by Unity yet. I COULD add the `IRequiredService` as a required constructor parameter, but then I'd need to refactor every constructor of every derived class to also include that parameter.

I was wondering if there's a better way.

In short, I'd like to run a bit of code after a class has been constructed and after unity has filled all the class' properties marked with the `[Dependency]` attribute.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered putting `RequiredService.DoSomething();` inside a [`[InjectionMethod]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507483(v=pandp.30).aspx) call instead of the constructor?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Excellent suggestion. I must have missed that attribute. Feel free to turn this into an official answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting `RequiredService.DoSomething();` in the constructor you can put it in a  inside a [`[InjectionMethod]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507483(v=pandp.30).aspx) call, this will allow you to reliably know that `RequiredService` has been populated.